# C++ program freezes when accessing a huge array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531714/how-to-compile-a-vector-with-huge-amount-of-data-in-c) I asked how to compile a vector with huge amount of data because I wanted a vector with a dictionary of 107776 entries, and I couldn't compile it.

I solved it thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11531937/1529630)'s code:

```
char const * const dict[] = {"aaron",...};
```

But now the problem is that when I attempt to access one entry...

```
cout<<dict[431104]<<endl;
```

...the program freezes and Windows wants to close it.

Why does it happen? How can I solve it?

**Edit**: sorry, it was my fault. As  tbroberg and Seth Carnegie noticed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11567681/1529630), the mistake was that I thought that `sizeof(dict)` was the length of the array (instead of `sizeof(dict)/sizeof(*dict)`).
Therefore, 431104 was far out of the bounds of the array (its length is 107776).

Comment: You need to do what the comment in that other question suggested, put it in a file and parse it. You can't store that much stuff on the stack.

Comment: @up true. By the way i would recommend you to learn how to use debugger. It's really usefull tool :)

Comment: Is dict[] local or global variable?

Comment: @SethCarnegie I would expect this to put the array of pointers on the stack with the strings in the data segment, (not that putting it in a file is a bad idea.)

Comment: @tbroberg that is correct, the string literals will be in the data segment, but that doesn't matter; 107776 `char*`s would be around megabyte if each pointer is 8 bytes, and that's about the size of a normal stack.

Comment: How many strings do you have in your dictionary? Is it >= 431105? Does Windows give an error message when it closes? If you look at dict in the debugger, how many elements does it have? Can you inspect element 431104?

Comment: @SethCarnegie Ah, and 400k+ pointers is *very* likely to lead to stack overflow. So the pointers need to be allocated on the heap with new, regardless of where the array comes from - static data or file. The Windows stack size is so vast compared to embedded environments that I had come to think of it as limitless. ;^)

Comment: @tbroberg What is the heap? So, if it's better, in order to allocate `dict` in heap, must I use `new char const * const dict[]={...}` instead of `char const * const dict[]={...}` and that's all, or should I do something else?

Comment: Yes, new to allocate stuff on the heap, delete to free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allocating 107776 `char*`s on the stack, which might be enough to cause a stack overflow on your computer. You can try allocating the `char*`s on the heap and use an initialiser list:

```
const char** dict = new const char*[107776] {"aaron",...};

// ... use dict

delete[] dict;
```

That should fix the problem (if the problem is stack size, which I think it is).

Also, I just noticed that your index, 431104, is far out of the bounds of the array, which is of the size 107776 (I misread it as 1 million before). Are you sure your problems haven't just been out-of-bounds indices?

Comment: Ups! It seems you are right and 431104 is far out of the bounds of the array.
I wanted to get the length of dict (I knew it is 107776 because I calculated it with JavaScript), but dict.size() didn't work, so I did sizeof(dict).
Thanks to your answer I remembered that sizeof says the byte-size of the array (which isn't what I wanted).
If I replace sizeof(dict) by 107776 it seems it works!

Comment: @Oriol you can calculate the size of an array in elements by doing `sizeof(dict) / sizeof(*dict)`. Beware that that number is one past the end of the array if you use it as an index though.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `static` before `const`:

```
static const char *const dict [] = { "a...", ...
```

Now it is allocated in initialized data segment. Depending on abilities of your platform and compiler/linker it might just work.

The operating system will usually take care of caching/swapping of this data, so if the data are really immutable, it is the preferred method.