# Make an executable out of cpp, python and csv files?

Tags: python, c++, csv, executable

I have written a program which has a few cpp, python source files and csv files which are used for input and output between programs(one program file generates a .csv for input to another program file). The user additionally has to write 3 csv files as input to the whole program as a start as these inputs are huge since its a timetable generator program, which needs the university data as initial input. Can I make an executable out of this program structure?

Comment: Do you mean like `pyInstaller`?

Comment: @user348752, Do you mean like an installation - msi package? Are you calling python script from the C++ code or vice versa?

Comment: I'm calling the whole sequence of programs in a bash script.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile and link all `cpp` file into a single executable and also embed your python file in this program using [Python C API](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html).

```
#include <Python.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("This is the content of your python files");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

You can also compile your static csv files as [long strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-executable-using-gcc) or [resource files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library) inside the executable.