# GCC: i386 architecture of input file `../window.ui.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to embed a file called `window.ui` into my C executable, with the goal to access the contents later from within the code:

```
objcopy --input binary \
        --output elf32-i386 \
        --binary-architecture i386 ../src/window.ui ../window.ui.o

gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` \
    ../src/*.c \
    ../*.o \
    `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` \
    -o ../a.out
```

When compiling, GCC fails with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: i386 architecture of input file `../window.ui.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there any way to force GCC to still include the file?

I've also tried the `objcopy` with `--output elf64-x86-64`, and this compiles correctly *however* the contents are garbled up when reading.

---

Original [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5518591/9107324) which inspired me

Comment: How are you creating `window.ui.o`?  The linker requires address information to place it in the executable.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I'm creating `window.ui.o` with the `objcopy --input binary --output elf32-i386 --binary-architecture i386 ../src/window.ui ../window.ui.o` command mentioned in the question.

Comment: ... what _is_ `window.ui`? I don't get why you're using `objcopy` at all.

Comment: @TypeIA `window.ui` is an XML file with the UI design for Gtk. I'm trying to embed it into the executable because it's needed at runtime.

Comment: I see. That's a pretty evil method of embedding a resource. The input files to the linker all have to have the same architecture. Your system is x86_64 and that's what `ld` is trying to produce output for, but you're giving it an `i386` input. Change your `--output` flag to `objcopy` to `x86-64` and you should get better results.

Comment: `objcopy` needs an object file.  Are you just adding `.o` to the end of `window.ui`?

Comment: @TypeIA `--output x86-64` is not available on my system, but I think you mean `elf64-x86-64`? Unfortunately it compiles but the XML content is scrambled and garbled upon reading (for example: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` becomes `<xlvrin"."ecdn=UF8?`. Any idea what it might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"solved" by using gnu-ld instead:

```
ld -r -b binary ../src/window.ui -o ../window.ui.o
```

Couldn't figure out why `objcopy` didn't work though.