# How to force CMake to relink project on resources change?

Tags: cmake, linker, resources

I have a very simple C++ executable and a few `.txt` resource files. At build time I embedd the `.txt` files into the C++ binary via linker and then I load them at runtime (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622727/10355495)). That works great.

My problem is relinking. Whenewer I change the `.cpp` source of my executable and run `make`, the project rebuilds itself. However, if I change a `.txt` file and run `make`, the binary doesn't relink. How can I force CMake to watch changes to my resource files (`.txt`) so that when those change the executable gets relinked to contain the newest `.txt` resource files?

Comment: Can you show some CMake code for this? How are you adding the `.txt` file to the binary? That matters for finding a solution to this

Answer (score 3):

You can set a source property called [OBJECT_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html) containing the path to your `.txt` file. The file to set this property for should be any source that is included in your target.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Also, make sure to specify full path to the arguments of the `OBJECT_DEPENDS` property to avoid build errors.