# Is there anyway to compile/memorize a webm/mp4 file into an .exe program? (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, video, embed

Might be a stupid question.

I'm making a C++ windows.h application, and I'd like for it to play a short video. It would be nice if I could somehow(?) compile the video into the program — I plan on sending the exe to others, it'd be nice if I didn't have to send the video with it as a separate file for the exe to load in at runtime.

I'm running Windows 10, writing and compiling with just Emacs and g++.

Comment: https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/linking-a-binary-blob-with-gcc/

Answer (score 0):

This previous question looks like it would be helpful for your case: [C/C++ with GCC: Statically add resource files to executable/library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library)

Comment: That is helpful, but... You've produced a link-only answer. You can salvage it by summarizing the contents of the link so that future askers can recreate the information or find a related link when the original link rots.