# How to make a c++ header file smaller? The header file is generated with "xxd -i"

Tags: c++, xxd

We need to store some data as c++ header file, so that we can then include it in the build bundle and shipped with any applications that use it.

To do that we use

```
xxd -i data.png > data.h
```

This works well, but the data.h files is now as 6X large as the data.png file. That means, if the data.png is 4MB, the data.h would be 24MB.

May I ask if there is a way to compress the data.h file to a smaller size?

Thanks!

--- update ---

Thank you all for the suggestions! I think I could clarify the need here to provide more context!

1. the ideal way for us to consume the file is we can open it as input stream like

```
std::ifstream is;
infile.open("data.png");
somefunc(is) // a api function that takes std::istream as input
```

p.s. the file is not png file but a scripted model, I use png as example because I find it as a more generic problem of "xxd -i"

2. we didn't find a way to make it available as a file to be read, as the file system the codes actually searching would be in Android/iOS. (only files on the mobile system are available and the source codes would be zipped in the .so file)
3. with the header file we can do something like

```
std::stringstream is;
is.write((char*)data_byte_array, data_byte_array_len)
somefunc(is)
```

The source codes would end up built as a lib.so. In our tests, A 70KB data.h would end up adding 45KB to the lib.so.

Comment: Are you concerned about the size of the executable, or specifically about the size of your source code files?  Generated source code can often be large, but is it causing a measurable problem?

Comment: Why in the world would you put that into a header file? I could imagine it being exported from a binary or even included as a file to map it into memory. In any case, yes, you can probably put a compressed representation in there. Just gzip it or something like that.

Comment: Have you tried `gzip data.h`? Or perhaps just ship `data.png` and let your users run `xxd` themselves.

Comment: In the embedded world, a common function is to place the data into a source file, not a header file.  Thus if the data doesn't change, the file will only be compiled once.  The header may contain an `extern` reference to the data array.

Comment: With base64 you'll have just a 33% increase in size, I sometimes use that when I want to store some binary in my sources. Encoding and decoding routines are quite trivial.

Answer (score 0):

> May I ask if there is a way to compress the data.h file to a smaller size?

You can use any lossless compression algorithm. The `gzip` program is a common default choice on POSIX systems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This won't work because gzip is actually zipping back the file, you may think the data.png is zipped already (the data.png is actually a binary model file) -- also see my updated questions

Answer (score 0):

You can compile any binary file into an object file using `objcopy -I binary`. See [C/C++ with GCC: Statically add resource files to executable/library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library) for more details

Comment: That's new to me, is that available on Mac? I tried brew install but couldn't find lol

Comment: Should be. objcopy is part of gnu binutils package that normally comes with gcc.

Comment: This approach sounds interesting! In mac, we can install a tool called gobjcopy which is said to be mac version of objcopy and the target data.o is of similar size! But may I ask is there an easy way to copy the data.o to the build for use (I am using CMake)? and how can we import the data in our codes