# C++: Defining void* array in header file and declaring it in a cpp file?

Tags: c++, arrays, namespaces, header-files, void-pointers

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391467/declare-array-in-c-header-and-define-it-in-cpp-file) question and I tried to do as the answer to that question said. To use the `extern` keyword in the header file to define an array and then declare it outside of that namespace or class in a other cpp file.

It didn't work for me really, I'm not sure if it because I'm using a void pointer array (i.e `void* array[]`) or if it's just my ignorance that prevents me from seeing the problem.

This is the shortest example I can come up with:
**[cpp.cpp]**

```
#include "h.h"

void main(){
    void* a::b[] = {
        a::c = a::d(1)
    };
}
```

**[h.h]**

```
namespace a{
    struct T* c;
    struct T* d(int e);
    extern void* b[];
}
```

So the problem is that I receive the error:
IntelliSense: variable "a::b" cannot be defined in the current scope

And I have no clue why that is.

Comment: How is it briefer if you have to also post that disclaimer?

Comment: `int` is one character shorter than `void`... `a::b` is declared outside of a function, the definition should be outside as well, why are you writing it inside `main`?

Comment: So instead of fixing `void main()` you deleted the reasoning for why you typed something incorrect to begin with. Brilliant. And the definition of `a::b` needs to be at namespace scope, not block scope.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Because I wanted the shortest version possible, I used `void main`, because then I don't have to return anything.

Comment: @Linus It's perfectly legal to omit the return statement in `int main() { ... }`

Comment: `return 0;` is implicit for `main` in C++. Ok, that's an obscure detail...

Comment: @Praetorian Okay, I didn't know that. But that's due to my ignorance in the C++ language. What do you mean that it needs to be at namespace scope?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I'm defining it in the main function because I will access it from other places as well, and it doesn't make any sense to me to define something in a header file, I know it is legal but I think of everything in a header file as declarations.

Comment: @Linus There are places in the .cpp file that are not inside the function `main`...

Comment: @Linus [Here's an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/556e19461c33071e)

Comment: @Praetorian That was simple, it was my ignorance then... Would you mind explaining why it can't be defined in a method?

Comment: @Linus You declared a namespace scope variable. So it wouldn't make sense for the definition to be visible only within a particular block (in this case `main`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should declare main() as int ! See [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main) why.

Declaring your array as `extern` in a namespace means that it belongs to the namespace but is defined somewhere ele, normally in a separate compilation unit.

Unfortunately, in your main(), you try to redefine the element as a local variable. This explains the error message you receive.

You shoud do as follows:

```
#include "h.h"
void* a::b[] { a::c, a::d(1) };         // global variable belonging to namespace

int main()                  // int!!!
{
    /* your code here */  
}
```

The code will compile.  The fact that a::b[] is defined in the same compiling unit is accepted.  But the linker will complain because a::d(1) is a call to the function d returning a pointer to a struct, and this function is defined nowhere.

Therfore you should also define this:

```
namespace a { 
    struct T* d(int e)
    {
        return nullptr;         // in reality you should return a pointer to struct T
    }
}
```

Interestingly, struct T does not need to work for this code to compile and link.