# How to declare array in header and init in cpp

Tags: c++

I'm writing Saleae Custom Analyzer but I am also new to C++
This does not work inside of a class:
[Declare array in C++ header and define it in cpp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391467/declare-array-in-c-header-and-define-it-in-cpp-file)

How to do it in a class?

```
class SimpleSerialSimulationDataGenerator
{
public:
    SimpleSerialSimulationDataGenerator();
    ~SimpleSerialSimulationDataGenerator();

    void Initialize( U32 simulation_sample_rate, SimpleSerialAnalyzerSettings* settings );
    U32 GenerateSimulationData( U64 newest_sample_requested, U32 sample_rate, SimulationChannelDescriptor** simulation_channel );

protected:
    SimpleSerialAnalyzerSettings* mSettings;
    U32 mSimulationSampleRateHz;

protected:
    void CreateSerialByte();
    U8 mSerialText[3] = {0xAA, 0x01, 0x55};
    U32 mStringIndex = 0;

    SimulationChannelDescriptor mSerialSimulationData;

};
```

mSerialText is what I would like to init below in .cpp not in header:

```
SimpleSerialSimulationDataGenerator::SimpleSerialSimulationDataGenerator()
{
    mSerialText = {0xAA, 0x01, 0x55};
}
```

but in cpp it says 'must be lvalue'
1.Can I change length later on?
2.Can I change value later on?
My dream solution is to declare array in header file with no length and init in cpp file with random data.

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: I get what you're getting at, @NathanOliver, but only because I understand C++,  whereas Lukasz is a self-admittedly new to C++ and I think your answer is too brief.  So perhaps you could actually provide a little bit of text with your answer ... and maybe even write it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: 1) Did you try initializing array in constructor initializer list? [Example](https://ideone.com/OkKFPI). 2) "_Can I change length later on?_" Of an array? No. 3) "_Can I change value later on?_" Sure, you can manipulate the data in the array, in any way you want. 4) Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Prefer [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: @Wyck: You are absolutely right. On the other hand, Lukasz should read his C++ book; repeating the very basics of the language 50 times a day is not what any of us is here for.

Comment: Well I have read Quick Guide on Tutorialsoint but it is not really descriptive about vectors. Nevermind, I should have added: If annoyed by newbies then don't read. If You don't know how to ask google about a task how then find a solution? ->stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For variable length array in C++ use `std::vector`.

In your header file you will have this:

```
std::vector<U8> mSerialText;
```

And then in source file you can initialize it with {} syntax just like in your example like this:

```
mSerialText = {0xAA, 0x01, 0x55};
```

It has an index access with `operator[]` or `at` function with out of range checks. To insert new elements, call `push_back`.
You can read further information about how to use vector on [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: This just works with `std=c++11`, otherwise `extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`

Comment: He haven't said anywhere that he needs to use old version of c++.

Comment: But it is tagged with C++ only. Anyway, this answer is the way to go! Otherwise, the answer would be **use** c++11 and then follow this answer.

Comment: Since he said he is new to C++, I don't think he even knows what c++11 means. Also, `c++11` or even `c++14` is nowadays used by default if you don't change compile settings in f.e. visual studio.

Comment: @MarošBeťko: That's pretty short-sighted; there are plenty of OSs out there on which e.g. GCC 4.4 is still the default, which doesn't even _have_ C++11 or C++14. If the OP isn't aware of these distinctions, even more reason to explain them.

Comment: Thank You for the answer and understanding. Everyday I use python, sometimes C#, rarely C embedded. I was looking for array and lists in search engine, never thought of vector. C++ reminds me of embedded C.